# iOS - How To Detect Hints Of Possible Memory Leaks

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

When my app starts up, in my home view, my app takes up about 35MB. I see this in the Debug Navigator. When I go through the app completely (going through every single view while doing some user interaction), it takes up about 60MB.

The thing that's making me paranoid is that when I make my app's `UINavigationController` pop back to the root view (my home view), the app stays at taking up 60MB. I except all those `ViewControllers` that I left to be deallocated along with their data.

Is this a tell-tale sign of memory leaks in my app? If so, how do I find them?

I've just started addressing memory management in my app. I know basic memory management principles like avoiding retain cycles, avoiding unnecessary caching, etc. However, I'm fairly new to the concept of detecting memory leaks, so any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's might be a sign.

Read about Memory Monitor Instrument:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingPatterns.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html

Answer (score 1):

You Can Easy Check That With **Instruments**

Just Click On Xcode (Top Bar) Follow This :-

**Xcode ==>> Open Developer Tool ==>> Instruments ==> Leaks** 
[image]